# Setting Caps Lock as Hyper Key for Emacs

Tags: keymap

With an `87 key` mechanical keyboard and am running `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`, I want the `Caps Lock` Key to be the `Hyper Key` for `Emacs`.  Have selected a keyboard layout `Generic 101-key PC` and set `Make Caps Lock an additional Hyper`.

Yet the `Caps Lock` is reporting as `Super Key` in `Emacs`.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: This is unfortunately a “bug” of Ubuntu’s xkb, where both Super and Hyper do the same thing.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/423627/how-to-make-hyper-and-super-keys-not-do-the-same-thing for more information.

Comment: This bug exists also with X11 on FreeBSD.